AWS Lambda function times out while embedding and indexing with OpenAI API in EFS storage context
Title: AWS Lambda Times Out After Embedding and Indexing Step Despite 15-Minute Timeout and 500MB+ Memory Allocation
Body: I’m using an AWS Lambda function to process PDF files stored in an S3 bucket. The files are read from S3, parsed into text, embedded using OpenAI’s embedding model, and then indexed and stored in EFS using LlamaIndex. However, my function consistently times out right after the embedding and indexing step.
Workflow Summary:

Trigger: The Lambda function is triggered when a PDF file is uploaded to an S3 bucket.
File Processing:

The PDF file is read from S3.
The pages are extracted as text.


Embedding and Indexing:

The text is embedded using OpenAI’s embedding model (text-embedding-3-large).
The data is stored in EFS using LlamaIndex.



Problem
Despite setting the Lambda timeout to the maximum (15 minutes) and increasing memory allocation above 500 MB, the function times out during the embedding step. The CloudWatch logs show that the process takes around 6-7 minutes at the embedding step, but still fails to complete within the allotted 15 minutes.
Here’s the relevant code snippet showing the Lambda’s core functionality:
import boto3
import os
import magic
import json
# from urllib.parse import unquote_plus
import logging
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from llama_index.core import SimpleDirectoryReader
from llama_index.core import (
    VectorStoreIndex,
    Document,
    StorageContext,
    load_index_from_storage,
)
from llama_index.core.storage.docstore import SimpleDocumentStore
from llama_index.core.storage.index_store import SimpleIndexStore
from llama_index.core.vector_stores import SimpleVectorStore
from llama_index.core.node_parser import SimpleNodeParser
from llama_index.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbedding


# Setup basic logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

storage_dir = '/mnt/storage'
new_folder = 'TRANE_S123'
full_storage_path = os.path.join(storage_dir, new_folder)
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "******"

def process_files(content: bytes, file_path: str):
    try:
        file_type = magic.from_buffer(content, mime=True)
        logging.info("File type: %s", file_type)

        if file_type == "application/pdf":
            print("Its a pdf file..........")
            return process_pdf(content, file_path)
        else:
            raise Exception("Unsupported file type")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Error processing file: %s", e)
        raise

def process_pdf(content: bytes, file_path: str):
    try:
        print("Processing PDF file...")
        with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix=".pdf") as temp_file:
            temp_file.write(content)
            temp_file_path = temp_file.name
        
        pages = load_pdf(temp_file_path, file_path)

        # Clean up temporary file
        os.remove(temp_file_path)
        
        return pages
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Error extracting text from PDF: %s", e)
        raise

def load_pdf(pdf_path: str, file_path: str):
    try:
        print("Loading PDF...")
        reader = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_files=[pdf_path])
        documents = reader.load_data()
        pages = []
        
        for i, doc in enumerate(documents, start=1):
            pages.append({
                "content": doc.text,
                "page_number": i,
                "filename": os.path.basename(file_path)  # Get filename using os.path
            })
        
        return pages
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Error loading PDF: %s", e)
        print("error loading pdf   ")
        raise

# Main Lambda handler
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Extract bucket name and file key from the event
    print("Received event:", event)
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    file_path = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    file_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'].replace(f"s3://{bucket_name}/", "")

    print("Bucket name : ", bucket_name)
    print("File key : ", file_key)
    print("File path : ", file_path)

    if not bucket_name or not file_key:
        return {
            'statusCode': 400,
            'body': json.dumps({'error': 'bucket_name and file_key are required'})
        }

    # Initialize the S3 client
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

    try:
        # Read file content from S3 bucket
        response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_key)
        content = response['Body'].read()

        # Process the file
        pages = process_files(content, file_path)

        print("after processing filessss.......", full_storage_path)
        # Create the storage directory if it doesn't exist
        if not os.path.exists(full_storage_path):
            print("Creating directory....")
            os.makedirs(full_storage_path, exist_ok=True)

        # Set up the storage context for EFS
        print("settuppting storage context for efs..")
        storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(
            persist_dir = full_storage_path,
            docstore=SimpleDocumentStore(),
            vector_store=SimpleVectorStore(),
            index_store=SimpleIndexStore(),
        )
        index = VectorStoreIndex([], storage_context=storage_context)

        print("Creating document.............")
        # Create new documents from the pages
        documents = [
            Document(
                text=page["content"],
                metadata={
                    "file_name": page["filename"],
                    "page_number": page["page_number"],
                },
            )
            for page in pages
        ]

        print("Parsing dcument into nodes.......")
        # Parse documents into nodes
        parser = SimpleNodeParser.from_defaults(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200)
        nodes = parser.get_nodes_from_documents(documents)

        # Add page number to metadata
        print("Adding page number to metadata.........")
        for node in nodes:
            node.metadata["page_number"] = node.metadata.get("page_number", "Unknown")

        # Embedding and Indexing
        print("Embedding and indexing...............")
        embed_model = OpenAIEmbedding(model="text-embedding-3-large")
        print("after embedding .....")
        index.insert_nodes(nodes, embed_model=embed_model)

        # Persist updated index
        print("Persist updated index........")
        index.storage_context.persist(persist_dir=full_storage_path)

        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps({'message': 'File processed successfully'})
        }

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps({'error': str(e)})
        }


What I've Tried
I have:

Set the Lambda timeout to the maximum (15 minutes).
Increased memory allocation above 500 MB to ensure the function isn’t memory-constrained.
Configured VPC and IAM roles to ensure the Lambda function has permissions and network access.

CloudWatch Logs:
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 10006.53 ms  Phase: init Status: timeout
START RequestId: ae7f6301-908e-4aa5-9a60-fa6efb630797 Version: $LATEST
Received event: {'Records': [{'s3': {'bucket': {'name': 'assetintelligence'}, 'object': {'key': 's3://assetintelligence/rtu.pdf'}}}]}
Bucket name :  assetintelligence
File key :  rtu.pdf
File path :  s3://assetintelligence/rtu.pdf
Its a pdf file..........
Processing PDF file...
Loading PDF...
after processing filessss....... /mnt/storage/TRANE_S123
settuppting storage context for efs..
[WARNING]   2024-11-12T06:25:34.516Z    ae7f6301-908e-4aa5-9a60-fa6efb630797    No existing llama_index.core.graph_stores.simple found at /mnt/storage/TRANE_S123/graph_store.json. Initializing a new graph_store from scratch. 
Creating document.............
Parsing dcument into nodes.......
Adding page number to metadata.........
Embedding and indexing...............
after embedding .....
Error: Request timed out.
END RequestId: ae7f6301-908e-4aa5-9a60-fa6efb630797
REPORT RequestId: ae7f6301-908e-4aa5-9a60-fa6efb630797  Duration: 485739.26 ms  Billed Duration: 485740 ms  Memory Size: 1000 MB    Max Memory Used: 404 MB 



You might benefit from adding a few more debug statements so you can see which one was the last to emit?

Also why ignore the exception message. Would ignoring the exceptions thrown from a library be a smart way to debug issues?

I've added additional debug statements to the code. However, the line index.insert_nodes(nodes, embed_model=embed_model) is resulting in a request timeout error. Could you advise on potential causes?

What's the time delta between "after embedding ....." and "Error: Request timed out"? Does the call to index.insert_nodes(...) involve a network connection or is it all local memory/disk?

Do you have an idea what node count is? Could it be large enough to consider batching up the work?

@jarmod The time delta is between   "after embedding ....." and "Error: Request timed out" is around 6 min 30 seconds and it sends each document’s text to OpenAI’s servers to generate embeddings, requiring network connection.

@Ross Bush The node count is 274 and chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=200

If you set the Lambda function's configured RAM to the maximum (hence getting max CPU and max network) and the connection to OpenAI is indeed working but the total amount of work you're doing exceeds the max Lambda timeout then I'd say that you either need to look to ECS Fargate or consider breaking up the amount of work across multiple Lambda function invocations, each handling a subset of the documents (if that's possible), perhaps managed via SQS batching.

I believe that AWS Lambda does not support GPUs, which are crucial for the high-computation task required for this operation. As a result, I executed the code on a Runpod server, where it works as expected. However, I am currently facing a challenge with mounting the resulting embedding data directly to EFS. Could you please advise on how this can be achieved?
